# How to target arbitrary HTML attribute containing space in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

```
<a href="?p=978" title="last page" class="last">978</a>
```

I'm trying to target the `title` attribute above. I know that I could use the following if the html tag contained something like `id="last_page"`:

```r
link %>% 
    html_nodes("#last_page") %>% 
    html_text()
```

What I don't understand is how target arbitrary attributes, or how to target `id` or `class` attributes that contain space.

Comment: Sorry, wrong tag. Suppose that id="last page"; what do i need to do?

Comment: Try using `xpath`, Does `link %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="last page"]') %>% html_text()` work for you?

Comment: @nerdakgul I've edited your question for clarity and expanded on my answer to cover more cases and better address what I think you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 3):

For attributes other than `id` and `class` you can use something like `[title='last page']`. The following returns `"978"`:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

node <- read_html('<a href="?p=978" title="last page" class="last">978</a><a href="?p=blah" title="last page" class="last">blah</a>')

node %>% 
    html_node("[title='last page']") %>% 
    html_text()

# [1] "978"
```

I'm not sure, but I think an `id` attribute with space is a no no. Still, you could access it using the same strategy as above:

```r
node <- read_html('<a href="?p=978" id="last page" class="last">978</a><a href="?p=blah" title="last page" class="last">blah</a>')

node %>% 
    html_node("[id='last page']") %>% 
    html_text()

# [1] "978"
```

A `class` attibute such as `class="last page"` is valid, but it actually contains two classes `last` and `page`, and not one `last page`. You can access it using `.` with one or the other, or both:

```r
node %>% 
    html_node(".last") %>% 
    html_text()

# [1] "978"

node %>% 
    html_node(".page") %>% 
    html_text()

# [1] "978"

node %>% 
    html_node(".last.page") %>% 
    html_text()

# [1] "978"
```

Comment: Wrong tag. I know not the same :) Thank you.

Comment: @nerdakgul please don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `xpath` to select `id`

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

link %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="last page"]') %>% 
  html_text()
```